# How to do a xml parsing

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

I have this xml file: http://www.studiovincent.net/list.xml

I need parser with c#, to get values. Im using this code:

```
XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create("http://www.studiovincent.net/list.xml");
        while (xmlReader.Read())
        {
            if ((xmlReader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element) && (xmlReader.Name == "field"))
            {
                if (xmlReader.HasAttributes)
                    Console.WriteLine(xmlReader.GetAttribute("name") + ": " + xmlReader.GetAttribute("price"));
            }
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
```

but I get in OUTPUT this result:

```
name:
username:
age:
hair:
name:
username:
age:
hair:
name:
username:
age:
hair:
```

How Can I get this result?

```
Vincent
Hill
31
black
John
Tedelon
27
brown
Michael
Lopez
20
red
Frank
Lopez
25
black
```

and this result?

```
 Vincent
 John
 Michael
 Frank
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please post the XML (or a sample of it, if too long) in the question

Comment: this is xml file: http://www.studiovincent.net/list.xml

Comment: Your code refers to a price attribute, which is not in your xml.  I think you want the value of the element, yes?  The .Value property should get that for you.

Comment: yes, I need value element

Comment: @vincenzolopalo I know. I saw that in your post. The thing is that, 3 months from now, if the XML is not in the question's body and your link is no longer available, no one will benefit from the knowledge generated in this interaction.

Comment: Sorry I dont understand your comment: xml is in the question's body, this is xml file: http://www.studiovincent.net/list.xml

Comment: I highly recommend you to use Linq to Xml [http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/vstudio/bb387044.aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/vstudio/bb387044.aspx). It is the easiest way (for me) to get through an XML file.
_XmlReader_ is quite complex to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code will give you, your first result:

```
        using System.Xml;
        using.System.Xml.Linq;

        XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create("http://www.studiovincent.net/list.xml");
        XElement el = XElement.Load(reader);
        reader.Close();

        var items = el.Elements("resources").Elements("resource").Descendants().DescendantNodes();

        foreach (XNode node in items)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(node.ToString());
        }
```

The following code will give you, your second result

```
        var items = from item in el.Elements("resources").Elements("resource").Descendants() where item.Attribute("name").Value == "name" select item.FirstNode;

        foreach (XNode node in items)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(node.ToString());
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

These first two lines will help you:

```
using System.Xml.Linq;
var doc = XDocument.Load("http://www.studiovincent.net/list.xml");
var people = doc.Descendants("resource");
```

This library is called [Linq for XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387061.aspx)

Comment: This doesn't tell him how to get the output he's looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
string URL = "http://www.studiovincent.net/list.xml";
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(URL);

//To read an element you use
 List<XElement> myElements = doc.Element("list").Element("resources").Elements("resource").Elements("field").ToList();

        foreach (XElement element in myElements)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("{0} : {1}", element.Attribute("name").Value, element.Value);


        }
```

Comment: thanks roughnex, but if I need only:
Vincent
John
Michael
Frank
(field name="name">)